# My perfectly working Java code throws an exception in IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: java, inputmismatchexception

I've been using eclipse and OnlineGDB for my Java works. I recently started to use IntelliJ IDEA and I'm enjoying this a lot. But i tried to work one of my simple projects in IntelliJ IDEA about file operations. But it gives me an error during running. **I'm experiencing no problem in OnlineGDB with the exact same codes.**

```
import java.util.InputMismatchException;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.PrintWriter;

public class Main

{
    static void createFile() throws Exception
    {
        PrintWriter output = new PrintWriter(new File("input.txt"));
        output.print("2.5");
        output.close();
    }


public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
{
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    Circle[] circles = new Circle[3];

    circles[0] = new Circle(1.0);

    System.out.print("Radius of the second circle => ");
    circles[1] = new Circle(input.nextFloat());
    input.close();

    createFile();
    input = new Scanner(new File("input.txt"));
    circles[2] = new Circle(input.nextFloat());
    input.close();

    for (int i = 0; i<=circles.length-1; i++)
    {
        System.out.println( "c(" + i + ") radius = " + circles[i].getRadius()
        + " area = " + circles[i].area() );
    }

    float total = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i<3; i++)
    {
        total +=circles[i].getRadius();
    }
    System.out.println("Total radius of the circles = " + total );

    total = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i<3; i++)
    {
        total+= circles[i].area();
    }
    System.out.println("Total area of the circles = " + total);
}
}
```

---

```
    public class Circle
{
    private double radius;

    public Circle (double radius)
    {
        this.radius = radius;
    }

    public double getRadius()
    {
        return radius;
    }

    public double area()
    {
        return(Math.PI * radius * radius);
    }
}
```

---

It gives me the "java.util.InputMismatchException" error during these lines:

```
System.out.print("Radius of the second circle => ");
        circles[1] = new Circle(input.nextFloat());
        input.close();
```

Comment: Your code works for me in Intellij, I gave the input as 5. What input did you give?

Comment: I see your problem, perhaps you entered 2.5 as input. Well, 2.5 is not an integer. Integers are like 2,3,.. so when you give a non-interger as an input and your code expects to read integer, it will be problem. You are reading integer when you call - input.nextInt().

Comment: Oops, i forgot to change "input.nextInt()" part to "input.nextFloat()" in the sample code above, my bad. But it is not the problem. It is still gives me the InputMismatchException exception even though I changed to nextInt() to nextFloat() . And Im' giving both integer and float inputs like 2, 2.5, 0 etc... Nothing changes.

Comment: You'r inside IDEA, you be able to put a break point at ```throw new InputMismatchException(nfe.getMessage());``` inside Scanner.java to see what exactly going on. That'd be faster than guessing or analyzing the static code.

Comment: I think surround your `input.nextFloat();` with try-catch to the handle the exception. It's working fine on mine as well unless I put in a string then we get that exception.

Answer (score 0):

```
System.out.print("Radius of the second circle => ");
circles[1] = new Circle(input.nextFloat());
input.close();
```

I changed  `input.nextInt()` to `input.nextFloat()` 
Change part of code that expects integer to read float(or double, if you wish). You should be able to enter values like 2.5 and not get any error.

I explained in comment why you get error if you enter 2.5

Sample output:

```
Radius of the second circle => 2.5
c(0) radius = 1.0 area = 3.141592653589793
c(1) radius = 2.5 area = 19.634954084936208
c(2) radius = 2.5 area = 19.634954084936208
Total radius of the circles = 6.0
Total area of the circles = 42.4115
```

Comment: Yeah i made that change too, but nothing changed. What surprises me, is that I get no error in other IDEs or compilers, whatever they are. It only happens in IntelliJ IDEA. I try to surround with try/catch for Mismatch Exception but still same.

Comment: I ran the code in Intellij. I copy pasted your code as it is - with one change - I removed the import java.util.InputMismatchException; What input did you give? Did you just enter the number and press enter or did you do something else?

Comment: I removed the import java.util.InputMismatchException; line now and gave the value of 2.5 (and then 2, 0 ....) and pressed enter. But nothing changes.

Comment: Aah, I see, could it be that you are from Europe and "," and "." mean different thing? The locale in Europe is different from say US or other Anglophone countries. Can you just enter 2 (without comma and without dot)? If that does not work, please tell me the EXACT input (including space,comma, dot etc) that you entered.

Comment: Entered just 2 and still gives the exception. 2, 2.5 or 2,5; the result is always same, throws the exception.

Comment: Can  you use some screen recording tool and record yourself giving the input and seeing the exception? There is no problem with the code. It works fine.